# Razor templating source code version

Tags: 2013, razormediator

I installed Razor templating v1.3.3.1 in our system (Tridion 2013 SP1). This is the last version of Razor templating.

I want to modify this version to add some log outputs. But in the source code of the project i can see in the trunk the version 1.3.3.0.

https://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/

Has someone the last version?

Comment: Check the tags https://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/source/browse/#svn%2Ftags%2Fversion-1.3.1

Comment: No. I need the tag 1.3.3.1 and the last is 1.3.3.0. the tag that you posted is 1.3.1

Comment: This question will probably be better answered by the maintainers of the project rather than on this general Tridion forum.

Comment: What kind of log outputs are you willing to create ?

Comment: I want to see wich template is failing and the line that is throwing the exception.

Comment: In Razor you can write down debug messages.

@Debug("Your debug message")
@Info("Your info message")
@Warning("Your warning message")
@Error("Your error message")

These messages are then shown in the template builder. This is one way to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: A while ago I made a branch for an implementation that provided logging of the generated source. So far this is just for a design discussion, so not tested etc. https://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2FsourceLogging

Answer (score 1):

The latest version is 1.3.3 as far as I can see. Where did you get 1.3.3.1 ? Is that someone's private branch?

In your branch, maybe you can look to see the differences in 1.3.3.1 and who checked them in. Then you could ask that person.

Comment: I spoke with Alex. He built the 1.3.3.1 version and uploaded the installer but he forgot to upload the source code.

He has a problem with his laptop. He said to me that he try to solve it and upload the latest version.